# Read QR code from terminal

Tags: terminal, qr-code

I am working on a C application that needs to display a QR code. Instead of writing GUI code, I was thinking of displaying it straight to the terminal. However, standard QR code readers expect the code to be square shaped, but when printed out in a linux terminal it appears rectangular shaped.

**How to tackle this?** Trying to print the code in a square form would probably be the best option to keep it compatible with standard QRC readers. To be honest, I don't even know if a QRC reader can interpret code being displayed by the terminal (perhaps it is readable depending on the characters used?).

```
······· · ·    ··   · ·······
·     · ·  ·· ··    · ·     ·
· ··· ·        ···    · ··· ·
· ··· · ·· ····   ··  · ··· ·
· ··· · ·      · ··   · ··· ·
·     · ·    ·  ····· ·     ·
······· · · · · · · · ·······
           · ···   ·         
   ·  ·  ·  ·   ··     ··· ··
  ···· ····  ····  ·····    ·
 · ···· · · ··   ·  · ··  ·· 
·   ·  ··     ·   ·  ······· 
 ·  ··· · · ·· · · ·  ··     
 ····      ···· ·· ··· · · · 
· ·· ····   · ····  ··     ··
  ·      · ·  ··· ··  ··   · 
 ·· · ···  ···   ···       · 
    ·· ·  ·· ·  ·  ··· ·   ··
·    ··  ··  ·  · ·  · ·   ··
    ··  ···· ·· · ·     ··   
·   · ·    ·  ·· ·  ····· · ·
        · ···   ··· ·   ·  ··
·······  ··  ·    · · · ···· 
·     ·    ·· ···   ·   · · ·
· ··· ·      ·  · · ······ · 
· ··· · ··      ·· ···· ··  ·
· ··· ·  ···  ·  · ··   · · ·
·     ·   · ·· · · ·  ··   · 
·······  ···     ··   · ·· ·
```

Comment: This may give you inspiration.. [`qrencode`](https://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/index.html.en) It can use ANSI sequences or Unicode characters for drawing on a terminal.  The ANSI drawings look impressive and testing with mobile phone works.

Comment: For example, you can check out the implementation of UTF8 drawing: https://github.com/fukuchi/libqrencode/blob/785c587542b24cc86/qrenc.c#L841

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on the exact font being used and if your terminal supports the characters, but I would try the following for each black square you need: ██

That's two U+2588 FULL BLOCK characters. Then, for each white square, just use two regular spaces.

Edit: Just read through Cong Ma's comment and the source code linked. Briefly glancing over it, it looks like they use a variant of this idea, but instead use half block characters (▀ and ▄) printing two rows at a time so that the output ends up being a quarter of the size that my method above would be.